# ERROR: Unable to process Jar entry - Selenium/Maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, tomcat, jar

I am trying to deploy my Maven project on Tomcat within Eclipse, but since I just added a new Selenium dependency I am now getting this error every time I start the server:

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/Users/ash/eclipse-workspace/my-project/target/my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/selenium-api-3.14.0.jar!/] for annotations
```

This is the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried following advice given on related questions, as it seems people have had this issue with a variety of different dependencies. The advice included using the latest version of the dependency, or deleting the dependency and jar files from the lib folder, and then re-adding them and rebuilding Maven before I deploy the project, but I had no luck. Has anyone got an idea of how I can fix this? I need to use Selenium to test my web app.

(I'm using the tomcat7-maven-plugin if that makes any difference.)

Comment: The problem is the given module-info.class file cause it's related to Java 9 and Tomcat 7 can't handle this obviously...